# How to remove Spring Cloud Config Server cache

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is there a way to remove the cache that is kept in the Configuration Server when using the Git backend? After configurations are merged to the target branch, the configuration server takes some time to get the changes.

It seems as if the Config Server has a local cache and a poll time of around 1 or 2 minutes. This isn't good because it is necessary to wait an undefined time to be able to re-deploy an application so it gets the latest configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `force-pull` property. It will reload configs immediately.

```
sring:
  cloud:
    config:
     server:
       git:
         uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
         force-pull: true
```